# how to add google map in smart device application?

Tags: smartphone

I am developing smart device application. I want to know whether we need to implement the google map by using html form or window form? Can we add both the static map and dynamic google map in smart device mobile application? Can u provide me a hyperlink from which i will get step by step description of how to implement the google map in smart device application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either Google Static Maps API or Google Maps API version 3, which is optimized to be able to be used in mobile devices. If you want interactivity, use the Maps API v3. When you just want to show a static map, use the static api.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/

From there you can get to the developer's guide, tutorial, and api reference.